# reset variable in recursive method back to zero after its done/before its called again?

Tags: java, recursion

I was given the task to code the following recursive method. midresult is supposed to be 0 when I call the method. It works if I call the method just once, but because I have this midresult variable, as soon as I call it more than once in a row it returns wrong values because it adds up midresult.

How do I set back midresult to 0 each time after the method is done running? Im not allowed to put it in my main method, but I can't put it into the actual recursive method because this will mess up the recursion right?

eg for x=5, y=9 the result should be 15, which works if I only call the method once. But if I call it with x=5 and y=9 after calling it with other  xy values the return value is wrong.

```
static int value;

public static int recursivemethod(int x, int y) {
   // TODO
   if(x==0) {
      return y + value;
   }
   else{
      if((x+value)%2==0) {
         value+= (x/2);
         int temp= y;
         y=(x/2);
         x=temp;
         return recursivemethod(x, y);
      }
      else {
         value+= y;
         x-=1;
         y=(y/2);
         return recursivemethod(x, y);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Combining recursion with global state is a pretty bad idea. Is that really a requirement of your assignment?

Comment: *for x=5, y=9 the result should be 15*.  Why?  Perhaps if you explain more about what you are trying to achieve, a solution could be provided that doesn't require external state.  And `recursiveMethod` is not a very good description of what it really does.

Comment: Well, if you're implementing a recursive method you must have a base case where the recursive calls will terminate. You could use that to reset `midresult`. Like @UnholySheep said though, it seems strange that this needs to be a global variable...

Comment: Please don't delete questions that received answers

Comment: Please don't change the question so that it invalidates answers.  If you have a new question, post a new question, linking back to the original question if if clarifies things

Comment: Also adding closed is unnecessary, if the an answer has solved your issue, then use the tick next to it to indicate that that answer helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Please select a correct answer if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

You're storing recursion results in a global variable. It is initialized to 0; this is why your first function call is working; after that, however, whatever value is stored in `midresult` afterwards is what is used by later function calls. You mentioned you weren't allowed to modify main, so try changing your recursive base case

```
if(x == 0) {
    return y + midresult;
}
```

to this

```
if(x == 0) {
    int temp = y + midresult;
    midresult = 0;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a static variable to hold `midresult`.  In some circumstances, that can cause problems.  An alternative is to use a helper method to pass `midresult` as an argument.  That value will be passed to the helper when the original method is invoked. Then you don't need to worry about resetting it for subsequent use.

```
public static int recursivemethod(int a, int b) {
    return recursivemethod(a, b, 0);
}

private static int recursivemethod(int x, int y, int midresult) {
    // TODO
    if (x == 0) {
        return y + midresult;
    } else {
        if ((x + midresult) % 2 == 0) {
            midresult += (x / 2);
            int temp = y;
            y = (x / 2);
            x = temp;
            return recursivemethod(x, y, midresult);
        } else {
            midresult += y;
            x -= 1;
            y = (y / 2);
            return recursivemethod(x, y, midresult);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this might be avoided too if you explain the overall algorithm you are trying to recursively implement.  You can edit your question to do this.  Just don't change your existing code/approach as answers and comments have been provided based on that code.